# Why my ESP32-CAM won't power up with 5 volts?

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp32

I'm new into electronics and I decided to power up my ESP32-CAM with a 9V battery instead FTDI programmer (I measured it, it gives 5V to ESP32-CAM). I thought if I reduce voltage to 5V with [mini voltage regulator](https://aliexpress.com/item/32975391414.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2tur) it will work but it didn't instead it turns on red light and makes high pitched noise. I tried get logs for debugging but since I'm a programmer and not an electrical engineer, I failed (I seriously tried connect TX and RX to FTDI, GND and VCC to battery). What did I do wrong? (See my diagram below.)

[image: perfect diagram]

Comment: A 9V block battery is simply not powerful enough to power an ESP32 Cam. You could use a 6 x 1.5V AA pack or 2S Lithium Ion battery (7.4V) as an alternative.

Comment: Did you connect the board’s TX to the FTDI’s RX and vice versa? You also need to connect GND between the board and the FTDI board. But the high-pitched noise does not sound good. Have you tried lowering the voltage of the adapter a bit? Did it work with the FTDI adapter only? Does it still work?

Comment: @StarCat that was my first guess, but the figures I found seem to indicate otherwise, even for the worst 9V batteries. But indeed a good LiPo is probably a better option.

Comment: @jcaron yes it does still work with ftdi programmer and its not damaged i think 9v battery is the problem. i didnt connect ground to ftdi i will try that tomorrow

Comment: In my experience an ESP32 Cam that has a marginal power supply will perform a "brownout" reset as soon as WiFi is activated. Sometimes a large(ish) capacitor (10 μF or larger) between Vcc and ground, close to the power pins of the ESP32 board will help. Do you have any equipment such as a multimeter to measure the actual voltage at the ESP32 Cam's power pins?

Answer (score 1):

- Does it still work in the previous configuration using the FTDI programmer? Do that to verify that it hasn't been damaged.

  The ESP32-CAM has two VCC pins, 3.3 and 5.0; ensure that you've connected to the correct pin. Supplying 5 V on the 3.3 V pin could irreparably damage it.

  [image: ESP32-CAM pinout]

  <sup>[Source](https://dronebotworkshop.com/esp32-cam-intro/)</sup>
- Rule out the voltage regulator as a problem, and supply 5 V directly using a bench supply to verify that the fault isn't with the regulator.
- Ensure the battery you're using is good. Also, 9 V batteries are not generally used for higher-current applications. The [datasheet](https://www.uctronics.com/download/esp32-cam-board-specs.pdf) for the ESP32-CAM does not give clear power requirements, but does list 310 mA at 5 V. If the regulator was 100% efficient (it won't be), that would be ~172 mA from the 9 V battery, which isn't necessarily a problem unless the battery is moderately discharged.

Comment: so everybody tells me 9v battery is not good for esp32-cam. yes i checked board is not damaged, regulator works fine (checked with multimeter). i will switch 6x 1.5v batteries tomorrow like @StarCat said